# How to translate a Magento extension?

Tags: magento

What is the best way to translate a Magento extension?

I need to translate this extension: http://www.magestore.com/magento-auction-extension.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the module properly configures translation files (which is *should*), it would be possible to create translations for your language locales. In fact, many vendors will have language packs available. If not, search e.g. *app/code/community/Magestore/Auction/etc/config.xml* for the string ".csv"; if listed, find those files under *app/locale/en_US/*. If you were translating to German for Germany, you could copy this file to *app/locale/de_DE/* and change the second string (delimited by comma, enclosed in double quotes) from each line.

There are other translation mechanisms. If you only need to translate a couple of text instances, ensure that they are rendered through the translation mechanism (e.g. in PHP-processed files that they are passed through the `__()` method). These can then be aggregated in *translate.csv* in your custom theme's *locale* folder under the folder for the locale setting (e.g. de_DE).

Comment: I found the Magestore_Auction.csv file. Thanks! :)

Comment: There may soon be a new StackExchange home for questions such as this; [the proposal may be worth following (link)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento?referrer=HFqQT3Qeb2X27y6ehRWkiw2)

Comment: But why are all the lines double? Like: "Cancel bid failed!,Cancel bid failed!" Should I only translate the last part?

Comment: Correct. en_US is generally the default language/locale in Magento world so there are no translations in that file. Translated example would be: "Cancel bid failed!","Ausschreibung gescheitert!"

Comment: I have translated the file and uploaded it to the locale and also the en_US locale but it has no effect.

Comment: The language is still english

Comment: System > Configuration > Cache Management.

Comment: Super everything works :) For special characters save as UTF-8